# Laravel where - how to reference same modal with conditions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to use some custom logic inside a `where()` condition (Laravel 5.8), e.g. the below. The `where()` parameter will change depending on a variable. The code below doesn't work, but gives you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. How can I get the desired result?

```
\App\Model::where(function ($query) use ($quantity, $price_criteria) {
    if ($model->threshold_1 <= $quantity) {
        $compare = $model->price_1
    } elseif ($model->threshold_2 <= $quantity) {
        $compare = $model->price_2
    } else {
        $compare = $model->price_3
    } 
    $query->where($compare, "<=", $price_criteria)
}->orWhere...
```

Comment: `use ($quantity, $price_criteria,$model)` ?

Comment: Also `$model->price_3` would give you a value rather than a column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use a `whereRaw()` query to build your conditions, or build separate query conditions with `where()`/`whereOr()`.

Using `whereRaw()`,

```php
\App\Model::whereRaw("price_1 <= ? AND threshold_1 <= ?", [$price_criteria, $quantity])
          ->orWhereRaw("price_2 <= ? AND threshold_2 <= ?", [$price_criteria, $quantity])
          ->orWhereRaw("price_3 <= ?", [$price_criteria]);
```

Or using Eloquent,

```php
\App\Model::where(function($query) use ($quantity, $price_criteria) {
               $query->where("price_1", "<=", $price_criteria)
                     ->where("threshold_1", "<=", $quantity);
           })->orWhere(function($query) use ($quantity, $price_criteria) {
               $query->where("price_2", "<=", $price_criteria)
                     ->where("threshold_2", "<=", $quantity);
           })->orWhere(function($query) use ($quantity, $price_criteria) {
               $query->where("price_3", "<=", $price_criteria)
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can't. All you do here is building a SQL query that returns data and you can't access the data before fetching it. In order to actually filter on data this way you will need to retrieve all data first and filter the [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `$model` as parameter like `$quantity` and `$price_criteria` (and add some punctuation :)):

```
\App\Model::where(function ($query) use ($quantity, $price_criteria, $model) {
            if ($model->threshold_1 <= $quantity) {
                $compare = $model->price_1;
            } elseif ($model->threshold_2 <= $quantity) {
                $compare = $model->price_2;
            } else {
                $compare = $model->price_3;
            }
            $query->where($compare, "<=", $price_criteria);
        })->orWhere();
```

Hope that helps.